# Create table from two lists dart

Tags: list, flutter, dictionary, dart, text

I want to turn the two lists (shown below) into a table sort of like this:

### Faults | Severity

motor velocity: 7 | 3

Using faultItems[i] with corresponding severityList[i]. I want to be able to show the table in a Flutter app using dart. Any help is greatly appreciated!

1. faultItems list

```
[motor velocity: 7, motor velocity: 2, motor temp: 6, motor temp: 3, motor temp: 9, motor temp: 4, motor temp: 7, motor temp: 8, motor temp: 2, motor temp: 5, no motor comm]
```

2. severityList list

```
[3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

code:

```
List<int> severityList = [0];
  List faultItems = [0];
  var lastFault;
  var pairs = new Map<String, int>();

  Widget _buildFaultOutput(snapshot) {
    severityList.clear();
    faultItems.clear();
    //New growable lists with 0 set as the first value to prevent error

    var msg = snapshot.data;
   

    var faultList = msg["fault_list"];
   

    var numberOfFaults = faultList.length;
  

    if (faultList.length == 0) {
      return Text("None");
    } else {
      for (var i = 0; i < faultList.length; i++) {
        // print(faults);
        // print("i: $i");
        var faults = faultList[i];
        var motorCurrent = faults["fault"];
        var severity = faults["severity"];

        if (motorCurrent != lastFault) {
          faultItems.insert(i, motorCurrent);
          severityList.insert(i, severity);
          // print('added ${faultItems[i]}, severity: ${severityList[i]}');

          lastFault = motorCurrent;
        } else {}

        //TODO: add list of faults with key/value pairs (fault:severity): Text of "motorCurrent" in color of severity

        //TODO: Print each individual item from list with severity
        // return Text(
        //     "Number of Faults: ${faultList.length}\n$faultItems\nSeverity: ${severityList[i]}");

        for (var i = 0; i < faultItems.length; i++) {
          pairs[faultItems[i]] = severityList[i];
        }
        print('$faultItems');
        print('$severityList');
      }
      return Text(
          "Pairs: $pairs\nNumber of Faults: ${faultList.length}\n${faultItems}\nSeverity: ${severityList}");
    }
  }
```

Comment: If you can guarantee the lists will be the same length, you can just feed it into a `ListView.builder`, using `i` to index both lists. However, it would be better instead to create a class to hold related data in a single object (i.e. a `Fault` class with a `type` and `severity` field, for example) so you can only have one list to worry about.

Comment: The list varies in length depending on the number of active faults

Comment: But is it guaranteed that they will be the same length as each other?

Comment: Yes, I just realized what your question was. They are the same length as each other.